# Exploding a title and removing a part completly

Tags: php, wordpress

Currently when I explode the title **Example Artist - Example Song Name [CDQ]** I am able to get the **Example Artist** and the **Example Song Name** without any problems using the code below.

```
$title = htmlentities(get_the_title ());
$str = explode ("&amp;#8211;", $title);
$artist = $str[0];
$song = $str[1];
```

Now I am trying to remove the **[CDQ]** portion of the title, but it has to be the brackets and the content inside of the brackets because sometimes the titles include things like **[iTunes]**.

I am currently using WordPress for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `preg_replace` to replace strings in square brackets.

```
$title = htmlentities(get_the_title ());
$str = explode ("&amp;#8211;", $title);
$artist = $str[0];
$song = preg_replace('#\[[a-zA-Z].*\]#','',$str[1]);
```

It will match all letters from `a` to `Z` including the brackets.

In the off chance you might have numbers inside the brackets you can change to this:

```
$song = preg_replace('#\[[a-zA-Z0-9].*\]#','',$str[1]);
```

Comment: You are very welcome! and very generous with compliments :)

Answer (score 0):

You could use the following regex to achieve all of what you want:

```
preg_match_all('/([^-]*)-([^[]*)/s', $subject, $result, REG_PATTERN_ORDER);
$artist = trim($result[1]);
$songtitle= trim($result[2]);
```

Comment: This either didn't work.. or I am not understanding what in the world you're trying to say.. when I changed my code to fit what you said it just gave me an error what is the strings `$subject, $result`? I don't have those strings..

Comment: Oh, sorry. Instead of $subject it should have been $title. And if it complains that $result isn't defined add $result=array() before the code above, even though this should only give a warning.